# Character Replacement in a String in Java

Tags: java, string, character, replace

Currently, I have an array of Strings, each with random characters in it that are random in length. I want to replace every "A" with an "X", how would I come about doing this?

Example:

`String str = "ABCDEFGAZYXW";`

I want the String to become `"XBCDEFGXZYXW"`. I tried to use:

`str.replaceAll("A", "X");`

But it does not change the string. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str = str.replaceAll("A", "X");`

The `replaceAll` method doesn't change the string (strings in Java are immutable) but creates a new `String` object and returns it as a result of the function call. In this way we change the reference to the new object where the old one is not changed but simply not referenced.

Answer (score 3):

Strings in Java are immutable, you're on the right track by using `replaceAll()`, but you *must* save the new string returned by the method somewhere, for example in the original string (if you don't mind modifying it). What I mean is:

```
String str = "ABCDEFGAZYXW";
str = str.replaceAll("A", "X"); // notice the assignment!
```

Answer (score 3):

For just replacing a single character with another you can use `replace`:

```
str = str.replace('A', 'X');
```

As many others have already posted `String.replaceAll` also works, but you should be aware that the first parameter to this method is a *regular expression*. If you are not aware of this then it might not work as you expect in all cases:

```
// Replace '.' with 'X'.
str = str.replaceAll(".", "X"); // Oops! This gives "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

Comment: For reference, if you ever wanted to replace "." with "X", `str = str.replaceAll("\\.", "X");` will do that.  Regular expressions like their punctuation to have backslashes in front of it, if you want it to be taken literally (rather than as a metacharacter, like "." for "any character" or "$" for "end of the line").

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the result, viz:

```
str = str.replaceAll("A", "X");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try 
   str = str.replaceAll("A", "X");

Strings are immutable in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Basically **replaceAll** function will take two parameter, one is string  which you want to remove and second one is new string which you want to replace and its return type is String.

It will return you new string after replacement.

Here you are calling that method but not storing its new value in variable.
you can replace or print it like this

```
String string = "My Old String with Old value";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll("Old", "New"));
//Or
string = string.replaceAll("Old", "New");
System.out.println(string);
```

So in your code you should store it into your string object.

```
str = str.replaceAll("A", "X");
```